# How to scale controllers with angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have some angular app, that is really easy. I've put everything into one controller, but i want to split it into multiple controllers so every controller should do action that belongs to it, not have a lot of different function of different meaning in one controller.

Here is a code:

```
    var videoApp = angular.module('videoApp', ['videoAppFilters', 'ui.unique', 'angularUtils.directives.dirPagination']);

videoApp.controller('VideoListCtrl', function ($scope, $http, $filter) {

    $scope.getFilteredResults = function (category, data, callback) {
        callback = callback ||$filter('articleFilter');
        $scope.videos = callback(category, data);
        return $scope.videos;
    };

    $scope.setPageSize = function (pageSize) {
        $scope.pageSize = pageSize;
        return $scope.pageSize;
    };

    $scope.addFavorite = function (data, key) {
        localStorage.setItem(key, data);
        $scope.getFilteredResults(data, $scope.allData);
        return alert(key + " "+ data + " was added to your favorite list.");
    };

    $scope.addSelectedClass = function (event) {
        if($(event.target).hasClass("selected") == true)
        {
            $(event.target).removeClass("selected");
        } else {
            $(".selected").removeClass("selected");
            $(event.target).addClass("selected");
        }
    };

    $scope.formatDate = function (dateString) {
        var date = new Date(parseInt(dateString));
        return date.toDateString();
    };

    $scope.cacheLoad = function (url, allowCache) {
        if(allowCache == false || localStorage.getItem(url) && (parseInt(localStorage.getItem(url + 'time')) + 20000) < (new Date().getTime()) || (!localStorage.getItem(url) )) {
            $http.get(url).success(function (data) {

                $scope.allData = data;
                $scope.videos = data;

                if(localStorage.getItem('category')) {
                    $scope.videos = $scope.getFilteredResults(localStorage.getItem('category'), $scope.allData);
                } else {
                    $scope.videos = data;
                }

                $scope.categories = $filter('categoryFilter')(data);

                if(allowCache == true && parseInt(localStorage.getItem(url + 'time')) + 20000 < (new Date().getTime() )) {
                    localStorage.setItem(url, JSON.stringify(data));
                    localStorage.setItem(url + 'time', new Date().getTime());
                }

            });
        } else {
            $scope.allData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(url));
            $scope.videos = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(url));
            $scope.categories = $filter('categoryFilter')(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(url)));
        }
    };

    $scope.pageSize = 12;
    $scope.cacheLoad('http://academy.tutoky.com/api/json.php', true);
});
```

So, how to split this into multiple controllers and how to pass data between them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could split things out into Services, for example the following item could be a service in your code, that you then dependency inject into your controller:

- Your Cache logic, This is normally something you would want to reuse so it makes sense to be a service.

You might also want to make the following item a filter or directive:

- $scope.formatDate - Rather than calling this function everytime you want to format a date, it would be much easier in your html to call `{{ date | formatDate }}` or `<div formatDate>{{ date }}</div>`

You could probably strip out the pageSize too but it depends how granular you want to go.

Comment: Good point. I have multiple custom filters, but somehow I did not realize that this can be another one :D Ok, so Cachce logic should be definitely a service, but what about the "event handlers" like addFavorite etc? Should they stay in this controller, or is there any better space for them?

Comment: It depends on your app, if you are only ever going to have Favorites on Videos, then it makes sense to be in the Video Controller, if users can favorite things like Comments, Video Authors, etc, etc. Then it makes sense to make a more generic service.

Comment: In this case, its only videos, it's quite like just an assigement to learn something new. But I want to get that type of thinking about project design right.